# label displays sum of two QSpinBox (Python + Pyside)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qlabel, qspinbox

Could someone help me fix the code to display in the total column the sum of the two spinners 'Amount + Counter'. Currently the total label just displays the value of a single spinner. I need it to display the sum of both spinners. Any additional fixes or notes are welcome as I'm new to python.

Thank you very much.

BELOW IS THE FIXED WORKING CODE

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        #Add all GUI Elements to Class
        self.amountLabel = QtGui.QLabel('Amount')
        self.counterLabel = QtGui.QLabel('Counter')
        self.totalLabel = QtGui.QLabel('Total')
        self.amountSpin = QtGui.QSpinBox()
        self.counterSpin = QtGui.QSpinBox()

        self.totalOutput = QtGui.QLabel('0')

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(0)

        grid.addWidget(self.amountLabel, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.counterLabel, 3, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.totalLabel, 3, 2)

        grid.addWidget(self.amountSpin, 4, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.counterSpin, 4, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.totalOutput, 4, 2)

        self.setLayout(grid)

        # ACTIONS
        self.amountSpin.valueChanged[str].connect(self.onChanged)
        self.counterSpin.valueChanged[str].connect(self.onChanged)

        self.setGeometry(800, 400, 250, 80)
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple Calculator')
        self.show()

    def onChanged(self, val):
        #we ignore the val and just get the values directly from our spinboxes
        sum = self.amountSpin.value() + self.counterSpin.value()
        #and display them
        self.totalOutput.setText(str(sum))
        self.totalOutput.adjustSize()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Add all GUI Elements to Class
self.amountLabel = QtGui.QLabel('Amount')
self.counterLabel = QtGui.QLabel('Counter')
self.totalLabel = QtGui.QLabel('Total')
self.amountSpin = QtGui.QSpinBox()
self.counterSpin = QtGui.QSpinBox()
```

[...]

```
# ACTIONS
self.amountSpin.valueChanged[str].connect(self.onChanged)
self.counterSpin.valueChanged[str].connect(self.onChanged)
```

[...]

```
def onChanged(self, val):
    #we ignore the val and just get the values directly from our spinboxes
    sum = self.amountSpin.Value + self.counterSpin.Value
    #and display them
    self.totalOutput.setText(QString(sum))
    self.totalOutput.adjustSize()
```

Comment: Still produces errors after implementing...
I've updated  the code above to the latest which still produces errors.

Comment: I removed the backslashes in your actions lines, as those were throwing errors.

Comment: They were from your Post. I just forgot to remove theme after copy pasting your code. If it works now please consider accepting my answer.